# About bitmonero.conf

Tags: monerod

Please excuse if my question is stupid but with current monero daemon node running on Windows 11 i do NOT have a config file in default location C:\ProgramData\bitmonero
So because of the reason that support info is mainly for Linux (bitmonero.conf) and just do not know what are default values on different options, if I add start the monerod with --config-file (.\monerod.exe --config-file) empty for the name of the file or with somename no matter is this file will be created in default data location with options which is used from the command line or it is necessary to provide a file filled with options names and values?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT an any option to do this automatically for Windows.
I tried all possible variants with NO luck or result of any kind.The only option is to copy file bitmonero.conf manually and fulfill options that is needed to manually in it.Maybe this will be changed in the future.Thank you.